# Python argparse allow combined flags

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Is it possible for argparse to parse combined flags like this:

```
app.py -bcda something
```

In this case, I would want `something` to be set to `-a` and the rest would be stored True. Basically:

```
app.py -b -c -d -a something
```

I know most programs allow this, e.g. `grep -rEw`, but how hard would it be to do this with with argparse?

Comment: As Chris Barker noted, the answer is to use `-bcda` instead of `-abcd`. Combining is something that works out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with store_const:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_const', const=True, default=False)
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_const', const=True, default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you can call this from the command line either with `-a -b` or with `-ab` (or `-a`, or `-b`).

Edit: and if you want one of the flags to take an argument, you need to pass it as the last item of the chain. So if `a` takes an argument, you'd need to do `-bcda something`

Comment: `action='store_true` is more succinct.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found with a little Googling:

> Several short options can be joined together, using only a single -
>   prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a
>   value:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('-x', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('-y', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('-z')
>>> parser.parse_args('-xyzZ'.split())
Namespace(x=True, y=True, z='Z')
```

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax